# SSD - copying files performance?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd

When copying a large file, how many MB/sec should I expect on an SSD? How does it compare with a regular hard disk?

For example, in Windows 7 when copying a file it'll give the speed info ( mb/sec). What are the average values for SSD and hard disks.

Comment: Where are you copying this file from, another SSD or a conventional hard drive? Are you using verification of the file at all?

There might well be other posts discussing the relative read/write speeds of SSD and hard disks.

Comment: Just copying one (large) file from one folder to another on the same drive. No verification, unless Windows 7 also does it. Just looking for some real-world numbers, even though they can vary widely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can vary GREATLY.  Just checking out a few drives on Newegg, I see one:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233089

```
Sequential Access - Read: 220 MB/s
Sequential Access - Write: 135 MB/s
```

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820208445

```
Sequential Access - Read: up to 25MB/s
Sequential Access - Write: up to 8MB/s
```

A lot of SSD drives are pretty comparable to regular (though they vary much more)... They're big advantage is non-sequential reading/writing, because it doesn't have to spin to a certain spot on the disk, it can read and write anywhere at any time.

This conventional harddrive:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148506

http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/products/desktops/barracuda_xt/#TabContentSpecifications

```
Sustained data transfer rate 138Mb/s  (11.5 MB/s)
Average latency 4.16ms
Random read seek time 8.5ms
Random write seek time 9.5ms
```

So some of the faster SSD drives are faster than traditional drives, and some are slower.  As they get better at making them you'll see them going faster and faster because they aren't limited by the same constrains of spinning disks.

These stats aren't always all that meaningful though.  The best thing is to probably check out benchmark tests for more real world results like here:

http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-notebook-portable,1913-5.html

There are plenty of these out there:

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=SSD+performance+comparison

But you'll find the more recent ones are going to show SSDs in better light as they have been improving recently.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize the huge variation among SSDs, especially between the Intel and OCZ Vertex 2.

This site proved useful for me - http://ssd-reviews.com/

Comment: @Gabriel: Ya... I wasn't even try to find different read/write speeds... I just clicked the first two drives in the list of mid-cost drives and those were it.